# how do you run a function every 5 seconds in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a javascript which if I click on a div1, I need load_data1() function to refresh every 5 seconds. If the user clicks on div2 or div3, I need load_data1() function to stop. As the code below, when I click on the div1, load_data1() function runs after 5 second and stops, it does not run after that, any ideas what I might be missing here?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    var timeout;
     function timeout_init() {
        timeout=setTimeout('load_data1()', 5000);
        return timeout;
    }



    $("#div1").click(function() {
        timeout_init();
        });

    $("#div2").click(function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            load_data2();
    });

    $("#div3").click(function() {
             clearTimeout(timeout);
             load_data3();
    });

});
```

Comment: Check out diff b/w setInterval and setTimeout. Also refrain from using  string expression on these, use the function reference instead.

Comment: For future reference, for goodness' sake *please* Google first. A simple search for `how do you run a function every 5 seconds in javascript` would have solved your problem.

Comment: If you simply googled your title, your answer would have been in the first result...

Comment: @PSL, I am not very familiar with javascript, can you elaborate?

Comment: I was able to replace setTimeout with setInterval, it worked. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you want to use `setInterval()` instead of `setTimeout` which only fires the one time, `setInterval` will keep firing until you clear it

Comment: I followed your recommendation it is working but I do have a concern. if the setInterval value is 60000ms, when I click on a tab, it waits 60000ms to load the page. I really need the page to load when clicked on the tab immediately then refresh every 60000ms. Any ideas how I would do this?

Comment: just call your function first before the setInterval. from your example in the timeout_init function, you can do 
load_data2(); 
setInterval(load_data2, 6000);

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
window.setInterval(function(){
  /// call your function here
}, 5000);
```

It's an anonymous function that will run every 5 seconds.